# Strange AJAX/403 Bug

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-403

I'm working on this site for a client:
http://50.28.69.176/~mendonca/collections.php

And I'm using jQuery to fire AJAX calls to view the enlarged images in a pop-in (Facebook style). But, I've noticed that when I use the  buttons below the image to rapidly click through the image set I hang Safari or Chrome. Then when I try to refresh the page I get a 403 error.

Oddly, this doesn't happen in FF.

So, I'm not sure if this is my server or ... what it is.

Any help would be appreciated. Has anyone else ever run into this?

Comment: looks ok in safari in windows 7

Comment: tested okay in Chrome11, IE8 and FF4 in win7

Comment: If I click frenetically in Chrome 12, it hangs.  But if I wait for a few seconds, then it works OK again.  Try testing with a static HTML file (vs PHP) to see if that makes a difference.